# No enum constant org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol.CLIENT aws MSK

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, aws-msk

I am trying to run schema registry on EC2 
My kafka is running on AWS .

This is my properties file

```
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8081
kafkastore.connection.url=z-3.***:2181,z-***:2181,z-**:2181
kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://b-3.**:9092,PLAINTEXT://b-6.**:9092,PLAINTEXT://b-1.**:9092
kafkastore.topic=_schemas
debug=false

schema-registry-start /etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties &
```

When i runt this i get below error

```
kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to parse the broker info from zookeeper: {"listener_security_protocol_map":{"CLIENT":"PLAINTEXT","CLIENT_SECURE":"SSL","REPLICATION":"PLAINTEXT","REPLICATION_SECURE":"SSL"},"endpoints"

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol.CLIENT
```

I have changed it TSL ,PLAINTEXT and without both but all are throwing error .
I have connectivity from EC2 to MSK as well .

Apache Kafka version

```
2.2.1
```

confluent

```
sudo rpm --import http://packages.confluent.io/deb/3.1/archive.key
```

even if i dont mention broker url then also i get same error

Updating question based on Answer

**when no connection url mentioned**

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-97-54-99 ~]$ [2020-01-11 03:46:29,418] ERROR Server died unexpectedly:  (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain:51)
io.confluent.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "kafkastore.connection.url" which has no default value.
        at io.confluent.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:241)
        at io.confluent.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:76)
        at io.confluent.rest.RestConfig.<init>(RestConfig.java:299)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryConfig.<init>(SchemaRegistryConfig.java:358)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryConfig.<init>(SchemaRegistryConfig.java:354)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:41)
```

Mentioning `CLIENT://` or `CLIENT_SECURE://` is also throwing same error .

and MSK does provide `Plaintext` as well .I can see this in client information

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Confluent for the key? Also, the Deb key is for Debian, I believe, and you're using RPM, not APT

Comment: yes i am using RPM ..i got this from website ...

Comment: `deb/3.1/` is not part of the YUM instructions https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/rhel-centos.html#manual-install-using-systemd-on-rhel-and-centos

Answer (score 0):

If you configure `kafkastore.bootstrap.servers`, then you need to remove the Zookeeper connection string from the Schema Registry.

> Kafka based primary election is chosen when `<kafkastore.connection.url>` is **not configured** and has the Kafka bootstrap brokers `<kafkastore.bootstrap.servers>` specified

Try just removing that first.

Also relevant - https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+MSK+

---

Its not clear which version of the Registry you've tried to install, but MSK does not have any PLAINTEXT client connection string, as shown by the `listener_security_protocol_map`.

You would need to specify a different connection such as `CLIENT://` or `CLIENT_SECURE://` for a valid listener protocol, assuming PLAINTEXT still doesn't work

Comment: The other option is to use Confluent Cloud in AWS, which gives you Kafka, Schema Registry, and Control Center

Comment: I do not have option to use confluent Cloud on AWS ..But i have updated my details based on your answer ..Even though i removed Connection url i get same error ..I tried with all connection but still same error .Also MSK provide plaintext as well ..When i see this in client information i see two bootstrp url one TSL and Second PLAINTEXT

Comment: The `CLIENT` listener is mapper to the plaintext protocol that Kafka understands. The zookeeper client doesn't know what to do with `CLIENT`, which describes the error you get. Did you see the github issue I linked to? It seems people have a solution there

Comment: Yes i have followed this even before also ..But i tried all that they are discussing already. Finally they are also using PLAINTEXT://BROKAL URL

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your version .
I have also faced same issue after that i installed manually and it worked for me .

this is my exact installation step and schema registry start step

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0
curl -O http://packages.confluent.io/archive/5.3/confluent-5.3.2-2.12.tar.gz
tar xzf confluent-5.3.2-2.12.tar.gz
cd confluent-5.3.2/etc/schema-registry/

/home/ec2-user/confluent-5.3.2/bin/schema-registry-start /home/ec2-user/confluent-5.3.2/etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties
```

Comment: Maybe you should share your properties